# Angular 9: how to open URL in a new tab using route.navigate() with query string?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

In our application, on a button click within a table, I need to open a new tab containing details of a record in the table.
Using the below code I am navigating to a new URL. On the new page, resolvers are used to fetch details from back-end. Now the problem is I want to open this in a new tab.

```
 this.router.navigate(['/url/test'], {
      queryParams: {ip},
    });
```

I tried the below code. But it doesn't seems to work. It is redirecting to the default URL:

```
    this.router.navigate([]).then((result) => {
      window.open('/url/test?aa=' + aa, '_blank');
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't the `router` to open a window. Remove the call to `router.navigate` and just call `window.open`.

Answer (score 4):

I was using useHash as true for my urls, so when i navigated with hash in url it started working.

```
    this.router.navigate([]).then((result) => {
      window.open('/#/url/test?aa=' + aa, '_blank');
    });
```